# ocaml seems to be broken

Tags: gentoo, configure, sabayon

I tried to compile Opa web framework from source on Sabayon, because their main server has a hardware failure. However, when I tried to use configure I got: "Your ocaml installation seems broken, please fix it" message. I tried to reinstall ocaml, but it changed nothing.

```
$ equo install nodejs openssl mongodb ocaml git ocaml-autoconf
$ git clone https://github.com/MLstate/opalang


$ ./configure -ocamlfind `which ocamlfind` --prefix=/home/mictadlo/apps/
which: no ocamlfind in (/home/mictadlo/apps/Sublime Text 2:/home/mictadlo/apps/WebStorm/bin:/home/mictadlo/apps/netbeans/bin:/home/mictadlo/apps/pymodules/bin:/home/mictadlo/apps/bin:/bin:/home/mictadlo/apps/go_packages/bin:/home/mictadlo/apps/liteide/bin/:/home/mictadlo/apps/snap:/home/mictadlo/apps/node_modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.7.3:/usr/games/bin)
Checking your OS... Linux
Checking your architecture... x86_64
Checking ocamlopt... /usr/bin/ocamlopt.opt
Checking ocamlbuild... /usr/bin/ocamlbuild
Checking ocamldir... /usr/lib64/ocaml
Checking ocaml version... 4.01.0
Checking your ocaml setup... could not compile
----------
        /usr/lib64/ocaml/libasmrun.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
        collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        File "caml_startup", line 1:
        Error: Error during linking
        Command exited with code 2.
----------
Your ocaml installation seems broken, please fix it
```

How is it possible to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues that I'm noticing right off the bat.

1. The option `--prefix=...` doesn't appear to be right, it should be `-prefix ...`.
2. You need to resolve where `ocamlfind` is, without this tool you won't be able to proceed with the install
3. You'll need to install both the package along with its header libraries

   ```
   $ ./configure -ocamlfind `which ocamlfind` -prefix /home/saml/ocal/apps
   Checking your OS... Linux
   Checking your architecture... x86_64
   Checking ocamlopt... /usr/bin/ocamlopt.opt
   Checking ocamlbuild... /usr/bin/ocamlbuild
   Checking ocamldir... /usr/lib64/ocaml
   Checking ocaml version... 4.00.1
   Checking your ocaml setup... 4.00.1, Unix 64bit
   Checking for camlp4... /usr/bin/camlp4o
   Checking for perl 5... found
   Checking for java... found
   Checking for nodejs... found: node
   Checking for nodejs version... v0.10.25
   Checking for ocamlfind... /usr/bin/ocamlfind
   Checking for ulex... ocamlfind:/usr/lib64/ocaml/ulex, OK
   Checking for camlzip... ocamlfind:/usr/lib64/ocaml/zip, OK
   Checking for ocamlgraph... ocamlfind:/usr/lib64/ocaml/ocamlgraph, OK

   Congrats, you're all set. Installation will be done in:
       /home/saml/ocal/apps
   ```

After resolving the necessary packages + libraries I was able to install this on Fedora 19 without issue. There was a package on Fedora called "ocaml-findlib-1.3.3-4.fc19.x86_64", you're likely missing a package similar to this on Gentoo.